# Is it possible to link to the same page from wordpress page menu?

Tags: menus

I have a big one page wordpress site and a menu created from wordpress admin pages panel. I added everywhere in my main page such links like `<A NAME="gohere">` and similar. Now I need to add href's to the page menu name's like `<a href="#gohere">` Actually I do not know is it possible to do this from the wordpress admin page's menu or maybe anybody know where these pages are stored so that I could add the links manually in the file's. Thanks!

Tried plugin "Page Links to" and added something like `<A NAME="gohere">` as a link in where, but unfortunately plugin do not understand this,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you've to change code in loop
for example currently now loop is like

```
<?php if(have_post) : while(yourquery): the_post : <div>the_title</div><div>the_content</div> endwhile; endif;
```

Then Just Add this line also

```
<?php if(have_post) : while(yourquery): the_post <a name="$i"><div>the_title</div><div>the_content</div></a> endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Hello there! I have exactly the same problem... In which file should I change this code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "Custom Links" meta box, to add any arbitrary link as a menu item. You'll need to add the full-path URL, but that shouldn't be a problem.